# Non-separability of an $\ell_1$-like normed space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Consider the normed vector space that consists of all functions $x(t):[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $x(t)$ vanishes everywhere but a countable set of $t_k$ and

$$||x|| = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x(t_k)| <\infty$$
I would like to prove that this is not separable.

The normed space in question appears very similar to $\ell_1$. I am aware of the proof that $\ell_1$ is separable and it is not apparent to me why the same arguments do not hold for this space. Is there a counter-example function that can be constructed that shows that a countable dense set does not exist or does this proof require something more in depth? Hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x^{s} (t)=1$ if $t=s$ and $0$ if $t \neq s$. Then $x^{s}$ belongs to this space for every $s \in [0,1]$ and $\|x^{s}-x^{s'}\|=2$ for $s \neq s'$. Do you know how to use this to show that the space is not separable? [Hint: Consider open balls of radius $1$ around the points $x^{s}$].

Comment: Agreed except that $\|x^{s}-x^{s'}\|=2$. Also, I would like to add that this space is sometimes denoted $\ell_1([0,1])$, so the similarity to $\ell_1$ is not coincidental.

Comment: This makes sense but I guess I am confused by "countable set of points t_k", how can we have s in [0,1]?

Comment: For each $s$ $x^{s}(t)$ vanishes except on a  countable set, in fact it vanishes for all $t$ except $t=s$. So each $x^{s}$  is an element of the space. @xSkid

Comment: So does countable here refer to the cardinality of the set of non-zero outputs for a given function and not the countability of the input value of t?

Comment: @xSkid For each element of the space there is a countable set set outside which the function is $0$. The countable set is not fixed. It varies from element to element.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks!